# Find all line in a file which start with g or any digit from 0to9

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line, text-processing, grep

How do I find all lines in a file which start with g or any digit from 0 to 9?

Can any one help me using command line? I try and I know how to do if start with g but don't know how to do with g and 0 to 9.

Comment: Type `man grep` on the command line.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very simple use of grep with regular expressions. This will do it:

```
grep -E '^[g0-9]' file.txt
```

I'm not sure what part you need help with, but I recommend you read `man grep` and learn about regular expressions.

Note that you must use `-E` to enable "real" regular expressions (which are all you need to worry about), and protect your regexp with single quotes to prevent the shell from doing its own thing with it before `grep` sees it.  (Search "shell globbing" for more details.)

PS. For this particular search, the `-E` could be left out without ill effect. Don't leave it out unless you *know* it can be left out. (I'm only mentioning this because some people are very interested in this issue, as you can see in the comments.)

Comment: works just as well without the `-E`

Comment: This regexp does, and maybe on your OS the `-E` flag is on by default; but for everyone who is not clear on the difference between "basic" and "extended" regular expressions, it is wise to always use it.

Comment: this has nothing to do with `grep` flavours and OSes: the point I am making is that nothing from `^[g0-9]` is outside of BRE as [defined in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03)

Comment: The point I'm making is that the `-E` is there for the **next** time the OP, and other readers, will use grep. Anyone who knows what syntax is a Basic Regular Expression and what is not, they don't need to take my advice.

Comment: I agree with @iruvar.  The `-E` is an unnecessary complication.  The Original Poster didn't ask about BREs vs. Extended Regex, and nothing about the question or answer require that information.  It just adds a confusion that wasn't there to begin with.  You could also explain how to use `grep` with a file containing a list of patterns (`-f`) in case someone needs that information next time; would that improve the answer?  No it would not.  Let's keep answers simple and to the point; you can always add a "further reading" section at the end.

Comment: @Wildcard, of course I wouldn't go that far-- I'm not writing a manual. But my answer is "this is the kind of thing you use `grep` for, now go learn about regular expressions." The best and safest idiom for this use case is to just add `-E`. (Now if the question involved a complex one-off regexp for some specialized purpose, that would be a different matter.)

Comment: @alexis, a fair point, but I still disagree with including it in the actual command itself that you're giving as an answer.  I made an edit which you will hopefully agree with (or improve slightly); if it really conflicts with your intent please feel free to roll it back.  :)

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid it does conflict with my intent, which I thought I'd made clear: There's no reason to go into the differences and similarities between the two regexp flavors, and there's no reason to use basic REs unless you already happen to know them.

Comment: Extended regular expressions (EREs) are NOT "real regular expressions", they are **extended regular expressions**.  They are generally easier to read and work with than "basic regular expressions" (BREs) but are no more **real** than them.  Many scripts still use BREs, and there are many examples of REs on the net written using BRE syntax.  It's worthwhile knowing and having experience with both.  And also with "Perl Compatible Regular Expressions" (PCREs).  It's OK to express an opinion or preference, but don't overstate it and don't state it as if it's a fact.

Comment: @cas, I'm just trying to avoid opening that whole can of worms. That said, I agree the way I phrased it is oversimplifying. But I didn't mean it as a value judgment: in my own code I generally use the simplest tool that will do the job, and that's often a basic RE or a glob.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expressions used by tools like `grep` can understand boolean OR (`|`):

- Basic Regular Expressions

  ```
  grep '^g\|^[0-9]' file
  ```
- Extended Regular Expressions

  ```
  grep -E '^(g|[0-9])' file
  ```
- Perl Compatible Regular Expressions

  ```
  grep -P '^(g|\d)' file
  ```

Alternatively, you could use other tools:

- `sed`

  ```
  sed -n '/^g/p;/^[0-9]/p' file
  ```

  or

  ```
  sed -En '/^(g|[0-9])/p' file
  ```
- `awk`

  ```
  awk '/^g|[0-9]/' file
  ```
- `perl`

  ```
  perl -ne 'print if /^(g|\d)/' file
  ```